# Starting jenkins Slave agent using Jnlp using Task Scheduler always starts as headless

Tags: windows, powershell, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I am trying to find solution for the jenkins nodes to automatically connect to master in non headleass mode.

**Here is what I have done so far**

I have written batch script which calls the powershell script. Powershell script has series of commands to start the jenkins slave agent using jnlp.

This batch script is configured in Task Scheduler to run at the startup. The jenkins slave node is connected to master as soon as node starts up.
But execution of GUI test is not visible in the node when the test starts.

When I manually run this batch script from command line, it works fine i.e non headless mode and I can see the execution of GUI test.

I've read few articles about this kind of setup and none worked.

I also wrote a small piece of powershell script to allow a Windows Service to Interact with Desktop.  This script runs after the batch script to start jenkins slave agent. 
Task scheduler job is configured to Run as Administrator and I login as administrator to see the execution.

Since this batch script is running via Task scheduler I am guessing its running in a different session.

How do I solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put your script into shell:startup. 
On a Windows 10 machine with the Jenkins slave under the user you need, press Windows+R (Run...) and type `shell:startup` and put your script into opened folder. It will run once the user logged in.

This is how you'll see console and any windows it spawns.